# Transform a df with conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Hello I have a df such as :

```
Groups Seq VALUE 
G1 Seq1 0
G1 Seq2 10
G1 Seq1 20
G1 Seq1 2
G1 Seq3 0
G2 Seq1 0
G2 Seq1 0
G2 Seq2 0
G3 Seq1 8
G3 Seq1 7
G4 Seq2 0
```

and I would like to transform it as :

```
Seq  G1    G2    G3    G4
Seq1 TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE
Seq2 TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
Seq3 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Where `groups` are colnames and if a `any Seq value is > 0 within groups` then I put a `TRUE`, otherwise I put a `FALSE`

So far I tried this :

```
as.data.frame(test_df) %>% 
  group_by(Groups,Seq) %>% 
  summarise(
    x=case_when(
      any(Seq > 0) ~ "TRUE",
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Groups, values_from = x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pivot_wider` directly :

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = Groups, values_from = Value,
                    values_fn = list(Value = ~any(. > 0)), values_fill = FALSE)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  Seq   G1    G2    G3    G4   
#  <chr> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#1 Seq1  TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE
#2 Seq2  TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
#3 Seq3  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: You do not use the column ```Seq```? In the exemple there is only 3 columns but in the real df there are 20 Columns, and I need to be focuses only on those 3 columns

Comment: You can first `select` the columns which you are interested in or add `id_cols = Seq` in `pivot_wider` in above answer.

Answer (score 0):

Must be `VALUE` instead of `seq` in summarise()

Also this could be simplified to `summarise(x = any(VALUE > 0))` (not tested)